# How do I write a cloud function which creates a user in the Firestore database once a new user gets authenticated?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, backend

So far I have written the following code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.addAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate((event) => {
  const user = event.data; // The firebase user
  const id = user.uid;

  return admin
    .database()
    .ref("/users/" + id)
    .set("ok");
});
```

The idea here is to execute a cloud function once a new user gets created. As this happens, I want to create a new node in the Firestore database. Under the 'users' collection I want to add a document with the uid, which contains a bit of information, in this case a String that says 'ok'.

When deploying this function it produces an error. How exactly should I go about creating it?

Comment: What error do you get? Also you can initialize Admin SDK just by `admin.initializeApp();` if deploying to Cloud functions instead of providing credentials yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The [`admin.database()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.md#database) returns the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/database) service. To use Firestore, use [`firebase.firestore()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.md#firestore). Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
exports.addAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate((event) => {
  const user = event.data; // The firebase user
  const id = user.uid;

  return admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(id)
    .set({ uid: id, ...user });
});
```